# Problems with '--isolatedModules' flag and RouterContext

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

When trying to run my deno app the following error comes out and I don't understand why .. Has anyone encountered this problem?

run command: deno run --allow-all server.ts

error:

```
error: TS1205 [ERROR]: Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.
  RouterContext,
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    at file:///Users/XXXX/Documents/DenoAPP/deps.ts:4:3
```

deps.ts

```
export { Application, Router, RouterContext, Context, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";
export { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/mod.ts";
export { hashSync, compareSync} from "https://deno.land/x/bcrypt@v0.3.0/mod.ts";
import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv@v3.2.0/load.ts";
export * from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v2.4/mod.ts";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [--isolatedModules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules) for an explanation.

Checking with [OAK RouterContext](https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts#L87) they do `export type` themselves.

So go with the flow and split

```
export { Application, Router, RouterContext, Context, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";
```

into

```js
export { Application, Router, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";
export type { RouterContext, Context } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the `export` can be shortened to: `export { Application, Router, type RouterContext, Context, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";`

Comment: new error: ***[ERROR]: Generic type 'RouterContext<R, P, S>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments. async getAll(ctx: RouterContext) { *** . code: ```export class SurveyController extends BaseSurveyController {   async getAll(ctx: RouterContext) {     const user: User = ctx.state.user as User;     const surveys = await Survey.findByUser(user.id);     ctx.response.body = surveys;   } ...```

Comment: @Boris That error is not related to your question (the export statement).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`type` modifier on the type names](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names) to resolve your issue. This is the idiomatic and recommended approach for TS version ≥ `4.5`:

```ts
export {
  Application,
  Router,
  type RouterContext,
  Context,
  send,
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";
```

Comment: Good to know its recommended like this.